# I am getting this no target error while installing angular\cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to Install angular\cli 
I Used This Command

```
npm install -g @angular\cli
```

I Installed node js too

I Even Turned off my Firewall and Antivirus but it did not work, and I get This Error and I do not Know How to Fix That.
What Can I do??

[image]

Comment: typo in your screenshot: you used an underscore instead of a dash for `-g`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using backslash

this is your code

`npm install _g @angular\cli`

how it should be

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

use forward slash `/` instead of backward slash `\`